# MS Search Server 2010 Express: Issue with crawl rules for site requiring cookie

Tags: sharepoint, search, search-engine, search-server, microsoft-search-server

I'm trying to create a crawl rule through the Central Admin for a non SharePoint site using Search Server Express 2010.

If I upload a cookie, I get an error after the crawl completes saying the parameter is invalid. I'm not sure what format the cookie file should be, but the various one's I've tried all provide this error and I haven't been able to find the expected format online. Can someone provide a link to the proper format?

If I try to specify a URL to obtain the cookie I get the the following JS error in IE8.

"Access is denied FormsAuthenticationProxyPage.aspx line 138."

I've also tried setting the cookie on the server side code of the site if the user agent matches the crawler, but this has also failed to work. Possibly the cookie does not get stored/passed back as the crawler crawls.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this fits for Express edition, but you should be able in central administration specify cookie for authentication

[http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee792871(v=office.14).aspx#procedure1](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee792871%28v=office.14%29.aspx#procedure1)